# Highchat yaxis offset property moves grid lines as well

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am looking for this design for y axis lables and gridline combination http://jsfiddle.net/ggfvggq8/6/ 
And this is the config I have used

```
yAxis: {
        title: {
        text: null,
      },
      labels: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'left',
        x:1,
        y:-8
      },
    },
```

And I need to have some fixed margin between y-axis and start of columns.

If I use offset property in yAxis then it adds the margin but also moves the grid lines and mess the required design. here is the fiddle and code

```
yAxis: {
       offset:30
    },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/caka5yfw/1/

Do you see any solution for the same?

Please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set Label `align` to `right` instead of `left` and remove `offset` as shown below

```
labels: {
    enabled: true,
    align: 'right',
    x:1,
    y:-8
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caka5yfw/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use axis' ticks to lengthen the gridlines. See [yAxis.tickWidth](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickWidth) and [yAxis.tickLength](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickLength) properties.

```
yAxis: {
  title: {
    text: null,
  },
  tickLength: 40,
  tickWidth: 1,
  tickColor: '#e6e6e6',
  labels: {
    y:-8
  },
},
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/5yab1y32/

---

[image: lengthen gridlines]